# Scraping website only retrieve 1st item on list Beautifulsoup 3.2.1. Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping usa.gov to get the index of U.S. government departments and agencies. The API for this listing was depricated in 2016. When I scraped the site for agencies with letter A the code only returns the name of the first agency on the list. I'm new to Python -- the assumption is I may need to write code to iterated through the classes to retrieve the entire listing. Thanks for your help

```
  import requests
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  import bs4

  url = requests.get('https://www.usa.gov/federal-agencies/a') #download webpage with listing A
  soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser') #create beautifulSoup class to parse the page
  fed_list_a = soup.find(class_ = "one_column_bullet") #extract class with information required

  print(fed_list_a.prettify())

  url_list = fed_list_a.find(class_="url").get_text()
  print (url_list)
```

Only this agency on the list of As was returned

AbilityOne Commission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use lxml as html.parser gave errors with this URL. You need to use find_all() not find() like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://www.usa.gov/federal-agencies/a') #download webpage with listing A
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'lxml') #create beautifulSoup class to parse the page
fed_list_a = soup.find(class_ = "one_column_bullet") #extract class with information required

# print(fed_list_a.prettify())

url_list = fed_list_a.find_all('a', class_="url")
for url in url_list:
    print (url.get_text())
```

Outputs:

```
AbilityOne Commission
Access Board
Administration for Children and Families (ACF)
Administration for Community Living
Administration for Native Americans
Administration on Aging
Administration on Intellectual and Developmental Disabilities
Administrative Conference of the United States
Administrative Office of the U.S. Courts
Advisory Council on Historic Preservation
African Development Foundation
....
```